# Git checkout using Jenkins pipeline is very slow

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In the initial phase , when the pipeline is checkout SCM stage (Declarative: Checkout SCM), it takes ~4 min, while the same checkout takes ~5 sec in another environment.

We have also observed that the underlying Git commands is same in both the pipelines. Also the git plugin version(4.3.0) is same in both environment.

Is there any way to reduce the time, we have also checked that all the git related plugins are up to date and have the same versions in all the environments.

Technology used : Jenkins Pipeline

Comment: You could try to ssh into the machine where the jenkins does the checkout and do a git clone manually. This way you could find out whether it is a problem with jenkins or the server.

Comment: Do you have antivirus interfering on that jenkins agent? Is it a VM? What kind of resources does it have? What does "Another environment" mean?

Comment: I've had issues before with jenkins running as a service in windows. Try starting your agent from the command line instead.

Comment: We have tried onto the server using git clone on cli And it was few seconds in DEV environment. But taking minutes in another environment. What could be the reason?